# SQL Server - collapsing multiple row values into one field

Tags: sql-server-2016

I'm trying to produce the result shown in the "Desired Results" section (in SQL Server 2016) in my screenshot below, where the objections associated with each borrower number are in one column delimited by commas instead of separate rows.

I don't want to restructure my database - I just want to display the results as requested for a customer report. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the STRING_AGG function which I didn't know existed to produce the results I need.

```
SELECT ht.Hearings_CaseID, Borrower_Number, STRING_AGG(Objection,',') AS Objection
FROM Hearings_Test ht INNER JOIN 
Hearings_Objections_Test hot on ht.Hearings_CaseID = hot.Hearings_CaseID
GROUP BY
ht.Hearings_CaseID, Borrower_Number
```